# What is wrong with the xml code

Tags: asp.net, xml

I got this question in an exam to specify what is wrong with this piece of XML code and I have no idea what the answer might be:

`<contact id=”10” name=”randomName” email=”first.last@gmail.com” phone=”09090909”/>`

I am guessing that the email would be prone to spam or something.

Comment: Are those quotes " or ”

Comment: Those quotes look like the invalid kind.

Comment: Are you sure that "nothing" is not an acceptable answer (ignoring the quotes issue for a moment, which might be accidental)?

Comment: They are " not ”
I could not find this " on my keyboard, so i typed ” without realizing it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer: you cannot name an attribute "id" in XML for your own purpose. It is a reserved name of the XML schema space which actually serves to identify a specific element to then do a look up by XML id.

### EDIT

The issue with the XML might be a modeling one. The fact you use attributes for name, email, and phone means that a contact can only ever have one value of each. Maybe your professor is after a new model e.g.:

```
<contact id="10" name="foo">
   <email>sdfsdfsdf</email>
   <email>sdfsdfsdf</email>
</contact>
```

Comment: Neither MSXML nor the .NET parser complain.

Comment: What I mean is that the attribute "id" can be there but it's not the id of your object. Instead, it's the id of the XML element.

Comment: There are no reserverd words in XML. There are however some reserved names (DOCTYPE, IMPLIED), but these are prefixed by a flag character.

Comment: See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/. Reserved may be the wrong word but id still has a specific meaning.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: Are you sure? How about `xmlns`? Would we be able to simply query that as an attribute?

Comment: @ThomasW.: Yes, I'm sure. To speak of the concept of queries you wander into XML-parser-land and it's implementation specific. The Perl module XML::Simple is an example where the attribute name `ID`is defined as a reserved name and you'll get into trouble using it. But that is not because of the XML specification. It's implementation specific. See [this](http://dougbunger.blogspot.se/2012/12/no-reserved-words-in-xml.html).

Comment: @DavidBrossard: There are very few rules to the [XML syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) and the XML in the OP adheres to all of them. So the correct answer is probably: `Nothing is wrong`.

Answer (score 0):

XML attributes are not intended to carry the object data.

Your XML should be structured like this:

```
<contact>
  <id>10</id>
  <name>randomName</name>
  <email>first.last@gmail.com</email>
  <phone>09090909</phone>
</contact>
```

Further reading: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

Comment: Using attributes doesn't make the XML invalid. As the website says, it's "My favourite way", so that's opinion based.

Comment: I interpreted "wrong" to mean why is it not best practice. The OP makes no reference to validity, nor did I.